# Set custom price bands for layered navigation in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to set some custom price bands for the layered navigation in magento. The price bands are specific and don't follow a set pattern so I can't use the step value in Magento's Layered Navigation configuration in magento. Is there a way to set up custom bands eg:

0.00 - 0.49, 0.50 - 1.99, 2.00 - 4.99, 5.00 - 9.99, 10.00 - 19.99 etc....

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its [own StackExchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension that you can set custom price ranges. It is not a free extension, so I dont want to share its name. But if you search "defining your own precise price ranges for better segmentation in magento", I believe you can find it yourself.